# RFC2822 datetime format to a usable datetime in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, rfc2822

I am receiving a datetime in the following format:

```
Thu, 18 Mar 2021 10:37:31 +0000
```

If I'm correct this if RFC2822.

I can't figure out a way to convert this to a 'normal' datetime that would be used by SQl server.
For example I want it to be:

```
2021-03-18 10:37:31
YYYY-MM-DD hh:mi:ss
```

I have tried things like CONVERT() and found a sketchy way by doing:

```
DECLARE @WeirdDate varchar(50) = 'Thu, 30 Jul 2015 20:00:00 +0000'
SELECT
CONVERT(DATETIME, SUBSTRING(@WeirdDate, CHARINDEX(',', @WeirdDate) + 1, 20))
```

But none of it is working that well.
Is there a way to convert this in a 'proper' way?

**edit:**

To clarify:
The format *should* always be the same as the provided example. Including the day name.

I am **not** sure that it will always be the same timezone. I could be receiving it from a different timezone. This is something to consider.

Comment: `select parse('Thu, 18 Mar 2021 10:37:31 +0000' as datetimeoffset using 'en-US')` appears to work (or `DATETIME` if you're sure it's always UTC), but with the caveat that this relies on the "default" date/time parsing of .NET, which can lead to surprises if your date is ambiguous. The alternative is to use a CLR function to parse it unambiguously, using explicit format specifiers in .NET. Parsing it using "pure" T-SQL code is technically possible but hideously unattractive (see, e.g., [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/dealing-with-custom-date-formats-in-t-sql)).

Comment: SQL Server version?

Comment: I am guessing the .NET solution suggested above is the best one... I don't see any case where it would fail. But I recommend parsing such data in (.NET) code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *could* achieve this with a "little" string manipulation is seems, and some style codes:

```sql
DECLARE @YourDate varchar(50) = 'Thu, 30 Jul 2015 20:00:00 +0000'
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(datetimeoffset(0),CONVERT(varchar(25),TRY_CONVERT(datetime2(0),STUFF(STUFF(@YourDate,1,5,''),21,6,''),106),126) + STUFF(RIGHT(@YourDate,5),4,0,':'));
```

This will, however, fail if you're using a `LOGIN` with a language setting which isn't an English based one.

If the value is always UTC, you can actually just use the "middle" `TRY_CONVERT` expression.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230078/discussion-between-salman-a-and-larnu).

Answer (score 0):

In my case the string comes with extra information

```
Mon Feb 15 2021 15:48:09 GMT-0500 (Colombia Standard Time)
Sun Mar 28 2021 09:59:51 GMT-0500 (hora de Ecuador)
Fri Jun 25 2021 08:54:28 GMT-0500 (Ecuador Time)
```

I used some `replace` functions to get rid of the extra information

```
TRY_PARSE( replace( replace( replace( replace( <<date_field>>, '(Colombia Standard Time)', '' ), 'GMT', '' ), '(hora de Ecuador)', ''), '(Ecuador Time)', '' ) as datetime using 'en-US')
```